# Else part is not working in Rails ajax form

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails ajax form to submit.When user will give the correct data it will search the database and do the operation accordingly.If user is giving the Wrong  data it should display user to alert message.But it is not happening like that.

I am explaining my codes below.

## home.html.erb

```
<% if current_admin %> 
<p class="flash-message"><%=flash[:notice]%></p>

    <div class="col-md-6" style="float:none; margin:auto;">
    <%= form_for :sdf ,:url => {:action => "scan_report" },remote: true do |f| %>
    <% if params[:receipt_no] %>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
        <%= f.text_field :Receipt_No,:class => "form-control", :value => params[:receipt_no] %><%= f.submit "Scan Report" %>
    </div>
    <% else %>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
        <%= f.text_field :Receipt_No,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Receipt No. scan" %><%= f.submit "Scan Report" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

## controller/homes_contorller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @sdf=TSdf.new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
    end
    def scan_report
        if @sdf=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:sdf][:Receipt_No])
            if @sdf && @sdf.HCSY_Status=='YES'
                @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdf.Sdp_Id)
                @hcsy_deatils=THcsyDetails.find_by_HCSY_ID(@hcsy.id)
                @woods=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(1)
                @burn=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(2)
                @good=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(3)
                @swd=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(5)
                @photo=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(6)
            end
        else
            flash[:notice]="Not Found"
        end
    end
end
```

In this form its only taking the correct input but if user is trying to give the wrong input the else part is not executing.Please help me to resolve this error and let me to know how can i make this ajax call in below format.

```
$('form').submit(function() {  
    var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
    }).success(function(json){
        console.log("success", json);
    });
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
```

Please help me.I am using Rails version 3.2.19.

Comment: Do you really have that formatting in the ERB file? It's impossible to read.

Comment: @Sergio,Now you can check erb file.Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: show your `params` as well

Comment: @Sergio,I am not getting you.Which params you are saying about.I have already given in controller file.

Comment: In the if statement, you're testing `params[:receipt_no]` and you think the else clause is never executed. One would then conclude that the problem is in the condition (`params` data), don't you agree?

Comment: @Sergio,yes agreed.I am adding again my requirement .If user will put the wrong receipt-no which is not present in DB in text field and submit form the sdf object can not create.In that case i want to execute else statement.Now it is ok for correct input receipt-no in text field and if part also executing.Can you now help me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75692/discussion-between-satya-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you send AJAX POST request to scan_report, and if it is successful it should render template `scan_report.js.erb`, and rendered template will appear in `json` variable in `success` callback.

But if params are not valid, the same template is rendered, but all instance variables are missing. And probably empty json is returned or an error appears in log.

Anyway, if you'd like to change `flash` in remote form, you should put custom code in `fail` callback. Something like

```
$("#flash").html('<%= j render flash[:notice] %>');
```